# Is it fine to pick stories in the current sprint which have external dependency?

Tags: scrum, agile, sprint, dependencies

We have a separate Scrum (front-end) Team to handle UI requirements. Sometimes, due to urgency, we end up picking stories in the current Sprint which depend on the front-end Team.

Whenever dependencies are not resolved in a timely manner, our execution gets impacted.
What could be the solution in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Scrum we look to create product increments each Sprint, not simply to do work. The direct solution to your question from the Scrum Guide is that you should have cross-functional team. That is, all skills needed to deliver a full product increment should be on the team.

There are circumstances where this may not be possible and you are stuck in the constraint. In that situation, you have to coordinate the efforts between the teams to manage the dependencies. However, in every case I've seen with front-end / back-end teams, there are far too many dependencies between them and it is far easier to just reform the teams to be cross-functional.

Comment: Been there. Tried that. Join the teams!